# Windows service trace debug messages

Tags: c#, windows-services

HI

I wrote a udp server classlibray i hosted it in windows form and it works fine. When i debug the trace and debug messages shows in output. When i host the cl in a windows service none of the debug messages is showing. Both cl and windows service is in debug there is no tracelisteniners specified so it should use outputstring.I even put a messagebox.show in the cl just to make sure the function is getting called in the windows service and it does.

So how do i get the trace/debgug message showing.The service is running as localsystem.

What am i missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Capture Global Win32" was not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Try DbgView program:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Comment: DebugView worked perfectly!! At first it didn't work but then I captured Global Win32, passthrough, and capture Kernal and it started working. The guys at Sysinternals are amazing!